# Importing custom types with custom import alias

Tags: typescript, next.js

Recently, I started upgrading my Next.js project to TypeScript and I have modified my import alias from `@/*` to `@*`. This is my new `tsconfig.json`.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "allowUnreachableCode": false,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "paths": {
      "@*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

I have stored custom types in **`/types`** folder like `User.ts`

```
export type TUser = {
  _id: string;
  name: string;
  ...
};
```

I can import anything on my app like:

```
import Header from "@components/Header"
or
import { ConnectToDatabase } from "@modules/mongodb";
```

But when I try to import my custom type `User` this way.

```
import { TUser } from "@types/User";
```

I get this compile error.

```
Cannot import type declaration files. Consider importing 'User' instead of '@types/User'.
```

But if I import like below, the error goes away.

```
import { TUser } from "@/types/User";
```

And if i rename the folder **`types`** to something else, I can import like normal.

```
import { TUser } from "@typesd/User";
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chances are, you're using type definitions provided by [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped), directly or indirectly. Since they publish the typings under the [org "types"](https://www.npmjs.com/%7Etypes) on npm, the path `@types/User` is ambiguous. It looks like you are trying to import a package named `User` from the @types organization.

This is why renaming the folder works - since it's no longer ambiguous whether or not you meant to import from your folder or a package under the organization, and also why `@/types/User` works for the same reason.

Comment: Ohh! I got it. What can I do now, continue importing like `...from "@/types/User"` or some other better solutions there?
Also I tried `declare module "User" {}` which allow to import like `import { TUser } from "User"`. But this looks to confuse me whether this is node module or custom type.

Comment: @BibekOli Personally I either go with `@/types/...` or rename my folder to `typings`.